# How to import specific values from a data frame into a variable in pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy, matplotlib

I have a folder with around 1000 `.txt` files, and I need to run the same code on each of them. One particular thing I need to keep track of is the count of a particular `haplotype`. I used 
`hap = df['hap'].value_counts().to_frame()` to create a new data frame with the counts of each `haplotype`. It looks something like this.

```
hap        count
1      347
5      171
3      168
7      140
6      56
11     51
9      33
2      31
10     3
```

I was wondering if there was a way for me to extract the count of just `haplotype` 7 and store its value in a variable.

One method that I have used is to use the `df['haplotype'].tolist()` command and then run a for loop with a basic if-else clause that keeps track of the count `haplotype` 7, according to the number of times it occurs in the list. But I'm curious to know if I can access it in the manner I've described above.

Comment: So you want the row where `hap` is 7? You can try `df[df['hap']==7]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the row where `hap` is 7 using the `[]` operator.

```
cnt = df[df['hap']==7]['count']
```

Comment: Check dupe how is correct solution with loc.